# On the joint numerical range of a pair of symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, matrix-decomposition, positive-semidefinite, common-root

Proposition 13.4 of Alexander Barvinok's [A Course in Convexity](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-54) shows the existence of the following result:

> Let $n\ge 3$. For two $n\times n$ symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$, and a PSD matrix $X$ with $\mbox{trace}(X) = 1$, there exists a unit vector $x$ such that $x^T A x = \mbox{trace}(AX)$ and $x^T B x = \mbox{trace}(BX)$.

This book does not show how to construct such a vector!

In Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook), on page 656, there exists a constructive method for a looser version of above (basically, no constraints on the trace of $X$ and consequently, the magnitude of $x$).

I could not so far use their proof for the above stronger version result and basically **construct** such $x$. Any proof, idea, or help?

Comment: The matrix you are looking for is $X = x x^T$. By cyclicity of the trace this equals the LHS.

Comment: That works if $\text{rank}(X) = 1$, but if $X$ has a larger rank, there is not a vector $x$ such that $X = xx^T$.

Comment: There are probably some existing algorithms in the literature of *joint numerical range*.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 You're right, I read the question as given $x$ find $X$ and not the other way around.

Comment: This result is equivalent to the convexity of the joint numerical range of a pair of symmetric matrices. A proof for arbitrary tuples of Hermitian matrices (so a stronger result) is [given here](https://people.wm.edu/~cklixx/jhw.pdf).

Comment: Thank you all for your kind and useful comments: @Rammus, JimmyK4542, user1551, Omnomnomnom, and Rodrigo de Azevedo. Still, I have not found a constructive method for my question but we'll keep looking!

Comment: @Sam you should say in your question that your question is how to construct such an $x$

Comment: @mathworker21 thanks and done!

Comment: For $\mathrm{rank}(X) \ge 3$, one may construct $x$ based on some decomposition of $X$ (omitted). I am interested in how to construct $x$ when $\mathrm{rank}(X)=2$ based on some decomposition of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

*Some thoughts*

Let $\alpha = \mathrm{Tr}(AX)$ and $\beta = \mathrm{Tr}(BX)$.
We need to find $x$ such that
\begin{align}
x^\mathsf{T} A x &= \alpha, \\
x^\mathsf{T} B x &= \beta, \\
x^\mathsf{T} x &= 1.
\end{align}
We use the Newton-Raphson method to solve the above system of three quadratic equations.
The Newton-Raphson map is
$$x \mapsto x - J^\mathsf{T}(JJ^\mathsf{T})^{-1} \left(
                                               \begin{array}{l}
                                                 x^\mathsf{T} A x - \alpha \\
                                                 x^\mathsf{T} B x - \beta \\
                                                 x^\mathsf{T} x - 1
                                               \end{array}
                                             \right)
$$
where $J$ is the Jacobian matrix given by
$$J = \left(
        \begin{array}{l}
          2x^\mathsf{T}A \\
          2x^\mathsf{T}B \\
          2x^\mathsf{T}
        \end{array}
      \right).
$$

Example. Let $n=5$,
$$A = \left(\begin{array}{rrrrr} -6 & -2 & 0 & -1 & 3\\ -2 & 2 & 2 & -2 & -4\\ 0 & 2 & 2 & -5 & 2\\ -1 & -2 & -5 & 4 & -2\\ 3 & -4 & 2 & -2 & 0 \end{array}\right),$$
$$B = \left(\begin{array}{rrrrr} 2 & -1 & -3 & -2 & 2\\ -1 & -6 & -4 & -1 & 0\\ -3 & -4 & 0 & -5 & -1\\ -2 & -1 & -5 & -6 & -4\\ 2 & 0 & -1 & -4 & 6 \end{array}\right)$$
and
$$X = \frac{1}{127}\left(\begin{array}{rrrrr} 29 & -9 & -20 & 16 & -1\\ -9 & 35 & 9 & -20 & 6\\ -20 & 9 & 26 & -22 & -8\\ 16 & -20 & -22 & 24 & 5\\ -1 & 6 & -8 & 5 & 13 \end{array}\right).$$
Randomly choose an initial $x_0$. After a few iterations, we get $x \approx [0.5829,    0.5326,    0.2344,   -0.4843,    0.2951]^\mathsf{T}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort @River Li. This numerical method definitely makes sense as there is proof showing the existence of at least one solution for the nonlinear systems that you wrote. Nevertheless, I am interested in constructing such a vector given matrices $A, B$, and $X$. Please take a look at page 656 of the Convex Optimization book to see what I mean. I am voting up though for sure. Thanks again for a useful answer.

Comment: @Sam You are welcome. Hope to see a solution as you desired.

Comment: Do you mind explaining how you got Newton's updates you have in your answer, please? I do not clearly see how you applied Newton's method on a system with exactly 3 equations and n (possibly strictly bigger 3) variables as the standard Newton's method requires the same number of equations and variables. Thank you so much @River Li.

Comment: @Sam It is the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of Jacobian. See: A. Ben-Israel, A Newton-Raphson method for the solution of systems of equations. http://benisrael.net/NEWTON-GI-2.pdf

Comment: @Sam By the way, you can go to find the algorithms based on decomposition of $X$ rather than Newton's method.

Comment: Sorry for my late response and thank you so much for your useful comments. I was doing research on them.